# Alguien sabe porque no puedo agregar la libreria import URLSearchParams; a mi proyecto

Tags: angular, angular7

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class YoutubeService {

  youtubeurl: string ="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems";
  apikey:string ="AIzaSyC3hi7PMcXt7oIUu1RQb51XbIPpkcgaLZc";

  constructor( public http:HttpClient) { }

  getVideos(){
   let url =`${this.youtubeurl}/playlistItems`;

  }
}
```

mi probema consiste en que anteriormente para yo, importar esa libreria lo hacia de esta manera:

```
impor{ URLSearchParams} from'@angular/http';
```

pero hoy en dia cuando busco la libreria de http aparece dentro de una carpeta asi `'@angular/common/http'`;
y dentro de esa carpeta no me aparece el `URLSearchParams;`

Comment: Hola, edita tu pregunta para que entenderla mejor y el código. Mira como hacerlo en: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Y parece que no estás importando la librería que indicas en el título. Que sería: `import {URLSearchParams} from '@angular/http';` Estás colocando 3 veces t en http

Comment: ya edite mi pregunta. gracias de antemano

Comment: Intenta ejecutar `npm install @angular/http@latest` y reinicia el servidor de desarrollo

Comment: esta bien, muchas gracias

Comment: me funciono, gracias nuevamente